# Does a function parameter that accepts a string reference point directly to the string variable or the data on the heap in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, reference, ownership, borrowing

I've taken this picture and code from [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

Why does `s` point to `s1` rather than just the data on the heap itself?

If so this is how it works? How does the `s` point to `s1`. Is it allocated memory with a ptr field that contains the memory address of `s1`. Then, does `s1`, in turn point to the data.

In `s1`, I appear to be looking at a variable with a pointer, length, and capacity. Is only the `ptr` field the actual pointer here?

This is my first systems level language, so I don't think comparisons to C/C++ will help me grok this. I think part of the problem is that I don't quite understand what exactly pointers are and how the OS allocates/deallocates memory.

[image: Pointer]

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("hello");

    let len = calculate_length(&s1);

    println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s1, len);
}

fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> usize {
    s.len()
}
```

Comment: What is the output you get when you run this code?

Comment: The length of of 'hello' is 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The **memory** is just a huge array, which can be indexed by any offset (e.g. `u64`).
- This offset is called **address**,
- and a variable that stores an address called a **pointer**.
- However, usually only some small part of memory is **allocated**, so not every address is meaningful (or valid).
- **Allocation** is a request to make a (sequential) range of addresses meaningful to the program (so it can access/modify).
- Every object (and by object I mean any type) is located in allocated memory (because non-allocated memory is meaningless to the program).
- **Reference** is actually a pointer that is guaranteed (by a compiler) to be valid (i.e. derived from address of some object known to a compiler). Take a look at [std doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html) also.

Here an example of these concepts ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0c09df41a283f3ecffd8188fb2d379e)):

```rust
// This is, in real program, implicitly defined,
// but for the sake of example made explicit.
// If you want to play around with the example,
// don't forget to replace `usize::max_value()`
// with a smaller value.
let memory = [uninitialized::<u8>(); usize::max_value()];

// Every value of `usize` type is valid address.
const SOME_ADDR: usize = 1234usize;

// Any address can be safely binded to a pointer,
// which *may* point to both valid and invalid memory.
let ptr: *const u8 = transmute(SOME_ADDR);

// You find an offset in our memory knowing an address
let other_ptr: *const u8 = memory.as_ptr().add(SOME_ADDR);

// Oversimplified allocation, in real-life OS gives a block of memory.
unsafe { *other_ptr = 15; }

// Now it's *meaningful* (i.e. there's no undefined behavior) to make a reference.
let refr: &u8 = unsafe { &*other_ptr };
```

I hope that clarify most things out, but let's cover the questions explicitly though.

> Why does `s` point to `s1` rather than just the data on the heap itself?

`s` is a reference (i.e. valid pointer), so it points to the address of `s1`. It might (and probably would) be optimized by a compiler for being the same piece of memory as `s1`, *logically* it still remains a different object that points to `s1`.

> How does the `s` point to `s1`. Is it allocated memory with a `ptr` field that contains the memory address of `s1`.

The chain of "pointing" still persists, so calling `s.len()` internally converted to `s.deref().len`, and accessing some byte of the string array converted to `s.deref().ptr.add(index).deref()`.

There are 3 blocks of memory that are displayed on the picture: `&s`, `&s1`, `s1.ptr` are different (unless optimized) memory addresses. And all of them are stored in the allocated memory. The first two are actually stored at pre-allocated (i.e. before calling `main` function) memory called **stack** and usually **it is not called an allocated memory** (the practice I ignored in this answer though). The `s1.ptr` pointer, in contrast, points to the memory that was allocated explicitly by a user program (i.e. after entering `main`).

> In `s1`, I appear to be looking at a variable with a pointer, length, and capacity. Is only the `ptr` field the actual pointer here?

Yes, exactly. Length and capacity are just common unsigned integers.

Comment: Thanks. This explanation is awesome.I can see now that s has its own memory address and its ptr value is the memory address in s1, which in turn has a ptr field containing the memory address of the data on the heap.

Comment: I think this explanation actually helped me understand borrowing vs moving better too. if i take println out and change it so this function calculate_length actually takes ownership of the value (move), i now see that s would be a shallow copy of s1, containing ptr, cap, len, pointing to the data on the heap. that's distinctly different than what s was in the borrowed case, just a pointer to s1. keeping the visuals of the memory blocks in mind, i can now see why &T and &mut are their own distinct types from T and mut T